# How to make package n import statements come out in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

How can I make pakage n import statements come out in IntelliJ?

Comment: please describe your issue in more detail. Please describe the expected result you wish to accomplish.

Comment: In this picture, the package n import statements aren't exist. In eclipse, the statements are written automatically. But in Intellij, they aren't. How can I make the statements be written automatically?

Comment: which statements? What do you mean with "package n import"?

Comment: for example,
pacakge  com.stackoverflow.~~~;
import java.util.*;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the package statement to be crated automatically, first create a package. (in the project view (left side of your window)) right click on "Thread" -> click "new" -> click "package" and enter the name of the desired package. E.g. "com.foo"

New right click on your package -> click "new" -> click "Java class" and enter the name of the desired class. E.g. "ThreadEx12"

Now your class is created with the package statement automatically. It should have "package com.foo;" on top.

When you reference classes it will also add import statements automatically.